# Unexpected output in Mapreduce program in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am working on **Hadoop**. My **output is coming twice than expected**.
I unable to understand why this is happening.
Please help me

Below is the **mapper class** :

```
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
 import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;

 public class StringMapper extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>
 {
       //hadoop supported data types
       private static IntWritable send;
       private Text word;

       //map method that performs the tokenizer job and framing the initial key value  pairs
  public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException
  {
        String line = value.toString();
        String out="";
        int count=0;
            out+=Integer.toString(count);
            send = new IntWritable(1);
            word = new Text(out);
            output.collect(word, send);                                               
   }
 }
```

Below is the **reducer class**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;

public class StringReducer extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>
{
  //reduce method accepts the Key Value pairs from mappers, do the aggregation based on keys and produce the final output
  public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException
  {
        int sum=0;
        while(values.hasNext()){
            sum=sum+values.next().get();
        }
        output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
  }
}
```

**Sample input :**
dashjdasdhashjfsda
dashjdasdhashjfsda
dashjdasdhashjfsda
dashjdasdhashjfsda
dashjdasdhashjfsda

**Sample output**
0 10

Here **output should be 0 5 instead of 0 10, because there are only five lines in my input.**

Comment: The code looks OK to me. How are you calling this job? Can you post your YARN cmd-line and report on the file structure on your HDFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Program seems to be OK. I copied your code and run it on my machine. It gives correct output i.e., 0 5

If you are using eclipse create a new configuration and also change your input directory. 
Then it might work.